# How to install Intel graphics driver for a Compaq DC5100?

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics

Installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my HP Compaq DC5100 3.2 GHz, 2 GB RAM, Intel internal graphics.

Can not use more than a 1080p resolution with my ILO LCD 26 inch monitor. I would like to have a larger range.

Comment: I don't know how you expect more than 1080p?

Comment: Does this screen actually support more than 1920x1080 resolution? I don't think so...

Answer (score 0):

Check the Intel Linux Graphics Driver installer, You can download it at the [Intel Open Source Technology Centre](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2013/intelr-linux-graphics-installer-version-1.0.2)

Download the newest installer (Version 1.02). It comes as a .deb file, which you can install using dpkg (or just doubleclick).

After installation, run the installer. The rest should be self-explaining. (hit "Next", as soon as available.)